# My .net core web app does not have an option to publish to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Looking online it looks like it should be possible to publish a .net core website to aws but I don't have an option to do so?

Comment: We're using AWS Beanstalk, works  quite alright http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html

Comment: What do you mean by "looking online"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Google

Comment: Can you provide a link to such a thing, or can you describe what you mean by "publish a .net core website"? Everything is possible on AWS, but it's not clear what you are actually asking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm hosting my .NET core web app in AWS using docker & amazon ECS

In visual studio 2017, right click on web project & select

```
Add -> Docker support
```

then push & run your images using Amazon ECS
https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/